# neo4j delete nodey with children and without

Tags: graph, neo4j

I have simple graph and i want to find category and delete it. If category has children, than delete category and all children. I've made deletion category with children with this command:

```
MATCH path = (c:Category)-[*]->(cc:Category)
WHERE c.id = "95bec604-5da2-4297-b792-5a866e292df4"
DETACH DELETE path
```

But this comamnd does not work for single node, without children. How i can achieve it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 0 as the lower bound for the variable-length pattern. By default it's 1, but when it's 0 (provided the label used for the end node is also on the start node) this will allow it to match even when there are no relationships from the start node.

```
MATCH path = (c:Category)-[*0..]->(cc:Category)
WHERE c.id = "95bec604-5da2-4297-b792-5a866e292df4"
DETACH DELETE path
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, this approach would work if you want to delete the entire path:

```
MATCH path = ( some path )
FOREACH (node IN nodes(path)  | 
     DETACH DELETE node
)
```